# Listings package: is it possible to exclude keywords from a specific language?

Tags: listings, color, keywords

I'm using the package `listings` to import R scripts from file (as they are quite long and already nicely typeset). I have defined the colors (blue for keywords) and style, and added a few keywords. Issues are (see also the MWE and output):

1. new keywords that contain a period (e.g. `write.xlsx`) are not recognized and are half black (also defining them as `{write.xlsx}` in the preamble doesn't work);
2. Some basic keywords of R are also used as options or arguments, and are (incorrectly) colored blue (e.g. `file`, `append`, `row.names`).

How can I tell listings to format as keywords only those terms that are followed by a `(`? 
Or alternatively is it possible to exclude some basic keywords?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{color}                                          
    \definecolor{codebackgr}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
    \definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
    \definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
    \definecolor{codered}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage{listings}                                       
    \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{                               
        language=R,
        backgroundcolor=\color{codebackgr},
        commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
            keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
            stringstyle=\color{codered},
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        breakatwhitespace=false,         
        breaklines=true,                 
        captionpos=t,
        numberbychapter=false,                     
        keepspaces=true,                 
        numbers=left,                    
        numbersep=5pt,                  
        showspaces=false,                
        showstringspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,                  
        tabsize=2
    }
    \lstset{style=mystyle}
    \lstset{
        morekeywords={read.xlsx, write.xlsx}
    }


\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={31-40}, firstnumber=1]{Script.R}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically I just want "write.xlsx" in blue and "file", "append" and "row.names" in black.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problem with the dot in the `read.xlsx` etc is the dot. You'd have to literate that or use only `xlsx`.

Comment: Thank you @TeXnician! Somehow I did not find that original question while browsing. The `literate`option did the trick, and I just defined `xlsx` for the other problem.